# PowerPoint animation or VBA issue: one name, picture appears, disappears, second name appears in the same place

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have been playing with animations in PowerPoint, but this relatively simple thing seems to be beyond my range. I want on the first (title) slide, one name with his details to appear below, then disappear on clicking (or pressing "n") and then another name should appear in the same place (where the first name was) with his details. Can this be managed with advanced animations? Otherwise I am open to use VBA macros also.

I would also like to add a symbol/picture (.bmp) for the first person to appear in the middle of the slide, which would disappear with that name, and then with the second name appearing, the second picture/symbol (.jpg) should appear in the middle of the slide. I will be glad if someone can show me how to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: better you either upload the File on Cloud or post valid attachment will help us to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Below written code will help you to make a presentation to display the lots of Names & others on a constant loop at PowerPoint slide.*

```
Sub CreateSlides()

Dim OWB As New Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\data.xlsx")
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)

For i = 1 To WS.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste (ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)

       ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

1. Add Microsoft PowePoint 15.0 Object Library, from Tool, References
   in Excel VB editor windows.
2. Create as many rows of data you want in Sheet 1 in the Named Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of effect, consider creating multiple slides and applying transitions between them. Simpler to understand and create, far simpler to maintain. And if necessary, you can print them as individual slides, whereas printing a slide with animations would give you just the one slide with all of the shapes piled atop one another.